# after forking a process, stdin is null (when configured as pipe)

Tags: node.js, fork, stdin

I'm writing a node js application that supposed to fork another nodejs application.

I want to be able to fetch output from that forked nodejs application in real time.

```
var maxLogintime = req.query['max-login-time'];
var playingUsersCount = req.query['playing-users-count'];
var cmdArgs = ['-u',playingUsersCount,'-m',maxLogintime];
var child = childProcess.fork(stressTestConsoleRunScript, cmdArgs, {
    stdio: 'pipe'
});

/* HERE IS THE PROBLEM:
 child.stdin is null
*/
child.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
    console.info('DATA: ' + data);
});
```

any ideas why stdin is null ?

## update

first of all... yeah i should have used stdout, but it doesn't change the fact that stdin, stdout, and stderr are all null instead of having a stream.

I tried to configure the child process fork command with the following:

```
var child = childProcess.fork(stressTestConsoleRunScript, cmdArgs, {
    stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe']
});
```

it didn't make any differences, all are null.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `child.stdout` if you want to capture output?

Comment: Read the docs: "In the following example, only the child's fd 1 is setup as a pipe, so only the parent's child.stdio[1] is a stream, all other values in the array are null."

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - thanks for your comments, updated main post.